# How do you say Doll Stories or Doll's Stories?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I am trying to make a logo and already made it saying

The Doll Stories

And I am not sure if this is incorrect?

Please help

Thankyou

Comment: What is the logo for? Stories about a doll, about several dolls or stories 'told' by a doll?

Comment: Are these stories about dolls or stories belonging to dolls?

Comment: This is about the dolls being alive and they have their stories

Comment: I had already designed and it says The Doll Stories.

Comment: Need help trying to find out if it has to be corrected to The Dolls Stories or if I am oky as a have it? thank you

Comment: Stories about several dolls could be termed 'The dolls' stories', but I'm sure your version is acceptable assuming that each story is about one doll.

Comment: Do the dolls tell their own stories in the first person (for instance "I am Sally, I am a clown doll...") or are the stories in the third person (for instance "Sally was a clown doll...")? If the stories are in the third person then either would be fine, if they are in the first person the possessive (The Doll's Stories) would probably be better because the dolls have more ownership of their stories if they are told in the first person.

Comment: If it's the title of a book, for instance, there is nothing wrong with *The Doll Stories*. Even if the dolls are alive and they tell stories, it's still a book *about* the dolls doing that. Modifying the grammar for the sake of something specifically correct (which doesn't actually matter when it comes to titles) could just take away from how natural the title already sounds. In other words, any different grammar in this case would probably look strange. In fact, even just *The Stories* would be fine. So, there's no problem using *Doll* as an attributive noun, and those often become singular.

Comment: The question says it's about a logo (an artistic design that represents something), but it sounds like you're really asking about a title. In either case, normal rules of grammar can be broken for stylistic reasons.